# Vue.js Dynamic JSON import based on select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, local-files

I am trying to display a large set of json datasets, 7000+ of them. I have a select on my page which allows a user to choose which dataset they want to view. A small example might be colors, only imagine I have 7000 of them. Here's a simple mockup.

```
Select a color [Dropdown]

Name: Red
RGB: 255 0 0
Hex: #FF0000
Complementary Colors: #00FFFF, #FFB03B, #B64926, #8E2800
Analogous Colors: $FF004C, #FF001A, #FF1A00, #FF4D00
Triads: #00FF00, #0000FF, #FF1A00, #FF4D00
etc.
```

I thought I could dynamically load the appropriate json file for display when the value of the select changed, but I learned that use of

```
this.$http.get
```

does not work for local files. I know I can import the file at the top of my export default statement, but I can't import 7000 files at that point in my code. Also, importing a file inside a computed value or a method is not allowed.

What is the best approach for handling large numbers json data files that I need to load dynamically? Am I forced to go to a valid API way of doing this? Or can I just simply load the files locally as requested by the dropdown selector?

Comment: _does not work for local files._ But they wouldn't be local to the client? They'd be on the server?

Comment: Have you looked into [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) ? You can load your data into a state and use it as needed.

Comment: @George Yes, I do mean local to the server and that is the problem. I don't want a user to have to download the whole set of data. Even if they are just text they take up to 5Mb.

Comment: @Adrien, does Vuex allow for loading them as needed? Again, I don't want to have to load them all given the size.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that I can load these files from the static folder. The relevant parts of the template and script sections look like this.

```
<template>
...
<select v-model="selected" @change="getData">
  <option v-for="key in data" v-bind:value="key.name">
    {{ key.name }}
  </option>
</select>
...
</template>

<script>
...
computed: {
  getData: function (selected) {
    var link = '/static/data/' + this.selected + '.json'
    this.$http.get(link).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.body)
      this.langData = response.body
    }, function (error) {
      console.log(error.statusText)
    })
  }
...
</script>
```